# Compiling EJS to Static Files Guide?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to port my site to Netlify, which is a static website hosting. However, I have a ExpressJS server that uses EJS to render and route things and trying to put everything together without EJS is becoming a nightmare.

For example, server.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const path = require('path');
const panelRouter = require("./routes/panel.js")


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views/assets')))
app.use("/panel", panelRouter)



function nocache(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.header('Expires', '-1');
    res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    next();
  }

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});


app.get("/robots.txt", nocache, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/robots.txt'));
});

app.listen(port=PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on: ${PORT}`)
})
```

and one of the routers im showing, panelRouter (panel.js)

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("../views/panel/home")
})

router.get("/about", (req, res) => {
    res.render("../views/panel/about")
})

router.get("/messages", (req, res) => {
    res.render("../views/panel/messages")
})

router.get("/achievements", (req, res) => {
    res.render("../views/panel/achievements")
})

router.get("/events", (req, res) => {
    res.render("../views/panel/events")
})

router.get("/exec", (req, res) => {
    res.render("../views/panel/exec/home_exec")
})

router.get("/erg_home", (req, res) => {
    res.render("../views/panel/erg_home")
})

module.exports = router;
```

Does EJS have a way to compile everything to a folder that I can easily deploy to Netlify or other sites that only host static files?

Comment: Hi! I am also having same problem. Did you find any working soultion?